# How to attach react component to existing react instance from outside of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, custom-element

I have a custom element and inside of it I want to use react and attach to parent instance, in order to whole stuff works as one.

```
// main.js 
function App () {
  return (
    <div>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
     <x-message>Hello World</x-message>
    </div>
  )
}

// x-message.js
class XMessage extends HTMLElement {
   connectedCallback(){
      this.__reactInternalInstance.moundChild(React.createElement('a',{}, ...))
   }
}
```

I want to render another element and attach it to parent react context inside of the `x-message` element.

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nr65r00Zp).

This example works in chrome and the browsers which supports custom elements. as you can see it does not know anything about parent and parent context when renders child element.

Comment: can you include an example in the question please, not an external link

Comment: added brief example, without working copy it would be difficult to understand what i want to achieve

Comment: Why try embedding one entire React container into another when you could just add your `XMessage` as a React component into the outer container?

Comment: for example if an user put `x-map` tag I will take it and render map inside user content.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have done this one and updated example